# replace value in a string with different values where the string changes

Tags: string, replace, character

I have a 5 character code that needs to be converted to a 4 character code. Additionally, the 5th character is either a 1, 2 or 5, and I need to convert them to 1, 5 or 9.  As an example, if my query returns '20155', I need to translate that to '2159'.  So far I have:
select substr(fieldname,1,1) || substr(fieldname,3,2) || substr(fieldname,-1,1) as newfieldname

This converts it from 5 to 4 characters.  What I don't know how to do is also change the last character to the new value as described above.

A sample of what I want it to achieve is:
20141 becomes 2141
20142 becomes 2145
20145 becomes 2149
20151 becomes 2151
20152 becomes 2155
20155 becomes 2159

Any assistance would be appreciated.  I am not a computer programmer - I am a functional analyst that has to validate over 500,000 rows of data, each row containing the fieldname above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "case when ":

Case when 2 then 5 , etc...

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm still getting an error.  Here is what I have:

Comment: select 
substr(fieldname,1,1) || substr(fieldname,3,2) ||
case
when substr(fieldname,-1,1) = 2 then 5
when substr(fieldname,-1,1) = 5 then 9
else substr(fieldname,-1,1),
sum(fte),
count(fte)
from
    personusis
    group by fieldname
    order by fieldname

Comment: Unfortunately, I keep getting a missing keyword error.

Comment: SELECT substr(3,2) CASE WHE N 2 then 5 END after the CASE

Comment: Hi, please mark this as an answer if it helped you resolve the issue.